# IIS Recycling app pool weird behavior

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

When I recycle my website with IIS I get this error until the recycling process is finish (so for about 5 seconds).

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the                                                   >content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure >that    the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of >the response were: '

Thanks

Comment: this is better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Your request expected a mime type of text/html. Since your response is blank, it has no content type header.

Why IIS even responds in this case is a mystery. It should (in IIS 7) have no response or be queued until the app pool is restored. Perhaps this server is behind a load balancer, and it is returning the blank response due to an internal 503 error.

Comment: The server is not behind a load balancer but I think, like you said, that the server is responding due to an internal 503 error. I have tried with another website in IIS and I don't get the error when I recycle. I will investigate more and do some test. Thanks!